# Which Date-Range Picker is best to use with angular 6

Tags: angular, npm, ngx-bootstrap, daterangepicker, angular-daterangepicker

Which Date-Range Picker is best to use in a angular 6 project if I only want to use bootstrap.
I have seen a lot of npm packages but is there any best date-range picker except ngx-datarange picker?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview ?

Comment: sorry i couldn't wrote but in bootstrap not in material.
and thnx by the way.

Comment: Doesn't this cover what you need? https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview - looks like range is supported?

Answer (score -1):

you can select one from these
https://angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker.stackblitz.io/

[Bootstrap daterange](http://luisfarzati.github.io/ng-bs-daterangepicker/)

Comment: I am asking about date-range picker not datepicker Sir.
But thnx for help.

Comment: @HarshitKankerwal Which date-range picker with presets is best for angular in dark mode?